# Hide Radio component

Tags: react-native

I use react-native-radio-input. I want to hide element if variable is not set

```
<Radio iconName={"lens"} style={quizDane.quest1[0].D ? "" : styles.hideIT} label={quizDane.quest1[0].D} value={quizDane.quest1[0].D}/>
```

style argument doesn't work

```
hideIT: {
    display: "none"
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

display none not exist in react native, you can show or hide element like normal react with a condition

```
{quizDane.quest1[0].D && <Radio iconName={"lens"}  label={quizDane.quest1[0].D} value={quizDane.quest1[0].D}/>}
```

Comment: that's works: {quizDane.quest1[0].A ? RadioPush(quizDane.quest1[0].A) : <Text> </Text>} Thanks <3